# Get grandparent entry_id with Structure

Tags: structure

In Structure you can get the parent entry_id using `{structure:parent:entry_id}` but is there any way to get the grandparent entry_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out...

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT parent_id as grandparent_id FROM exp_structure WHERE entry_id = {structure:parent:entry_id}"}
 {grandparent_id}
{/exp:query}
```